# Trait is not being reported as "covered"

Tags: php, phpunit, traits

I have a problem testing traits. One of my classes uses a trait and implements an interface. Interface methods by the way are being implemented by a trait.

When I run `phpunit` with coverage report enabled I see that my class is shown as 100% covered, interface is shown as 100% covered, by trait is shown as 0%:

[image: demonstration]

The class uses trait, methods from trait are being called in test suite, but still trait is considered uncovered.

Should traits be tested separately somehow? I know about `getMockForTrait()` method, but I would like to avoid it. Is there any way to fix the issue and to cover trait by testing the class itself?

Comment: My best guess is that PHPUnit doesn't see the lines in the trait as part of the class itself.  If you were to reflect the class and get its methods are the methods from the trait in the resulting array?  The zero lines for interfaces makes sense.  There are no lines of code to test in an interface since the interface is only defining a contract.

Comment: @Crackertastic, yep, methods are there. Actually the same problem is for abstract classes - they are not shown as covered though they are extended by tested class.

Comment: Hmm, must be a PHPUnit thing then if a reflected class sees the methods, hence the `getMockForTrait()` method.  To be honest I have only used traits once.  As far as not getting a count on abstract classes, I haven't encountered that before.  I'm using `4.8.16` in PHPStorm and I get coverage reported on my abstract classes when I test a class that extends it.

Comment: @Crackertastic, I actually have found an error: I have occasionally left `@covers` annotation in test suite (`@covers` was set for parent class only). Removing of the annotation fixed the issue.
Thx for your effort nevertheless:)

Comment: Your welcome.  Glad to hear you figured it out.